# Material UI referencing colours from palette elsewhere in the theme?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, themes

If I have set my theme up and declared the colours I want use in the palette for primary, seconday etc.  How do I reference those colours in an overrides section of the theme?

I am trying to only have colours in only one place like in SASS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [material-ui - how to refer palette in override?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61695520/material-ui-how-to-refer-palette-in-override)

Comment: Yes it does. Many thanks